# How to close connected multiprocessing pipes in Python properly

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a worker process that is fed with work and sends back the processed results to the parent process.

How can I close those two pipes properly?

What I did so far:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker(v: str, work_in, result_in):
    while True:
        number_str = work_in.recv()
        print('Processing', number_str)
        result = number_str + v
        result_in.send(result)


work_out, work_in = mp.Pipe()
result_out, result_in = mp.Pipe()

for number in range(10):
    number_str = str(number)
    print('Sending', number_str)
    work_in.send(number_str)
# work_in.close()

worker_process = mp.Process(target=worker, args=('_processed', work_out, result_in,))
worker_process.start()

for _ in range(10):
    processed_number_str = result_out.recv()
    print('Received', processed_number_str)
result_out.close()

worker_process.join()
```

The results are as expected (I hope). But if I don't close `work_in` than the program does not end, if I close it, it crashes with an `EOFError`.

I also welcome any stylistic or technical advice for using pipes in Python.

Answer (score 1):

When not closing `work_in` connection, the Process will never finish because it is in an infinite loop (`while True`). Thus, it will just wait forever for any incoming message.

When you do close work_in, the `while True` loop will reach `EOFError` as mentioned in the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.connection.Connection.

So, there are different ways to handles this:

If your app is not continuous (a definite number of items to process), then you can either use try and catch block to detect the EOF or use the `poll` method of connection to check if there is any items to process.

a. Using EOF and closing `work_in`:

```
def worker(v: str, work_in, result_in):
    eof = False
    while not(eof):
        try:
            number_str = work_in.recv()
            print('Processing', number_str)
            result = number_str + v
            result_in.send(result)
        except EOFError:
            print('No more data to process. Exitiing')
            eof = True 
        except:
            print("Oh we forgot this exception!")
            raise Exception("Something to note!")
```

b. using `poll` (wait for 1 second and check if there are any items, if not, exit) and not closing the connection `work_in`

```
def worker(v: str, work_in, result_in):
    while work_in.poll(timeout=1):
        number_str = work_in.recv()
        print('Processing', number_str)
        result = number_str + v
        result_in.send(result)
```

If your app is continuous, then you might need to implement a bit more complex process that enables sending a message to the subprocess via a different queue (or the same queue with a particular message) to let it know that it should terminate and then `break` the loop.